# Cannot convert value of type 'Range<Array<String>.Index>' (aka 'Range<Int>') to expected argument type 'Binding<C>'

Tags: swift, swiftui, foreach

I have this line of code

```
ForEach(exercise.equipment.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                let equipment = exercise.equipment[index]
```

Where Exercise is

```
struct Exercise: Identifiable, Codable {

@DocumentID var id: String?
let name: String
let muscleGroup: [String]
let equipment: [String]

init(id: String, name: String, muscleGroup: [String], equipment: [String]) {
    self.id = id
    self.name = name
    self.muscleGroup = muscleGroup
    self.equipment = equipment
}
```

}

Does anybody know why this error gets thrown for .indices in the ForEach loop?

Cannot convert value of type 'Range<Array.Index>' (aka 'Range') to expected argument type 'Binding'

Comment: It's recommended to not use indices with `ForEach`, change it to `ForEach(exercise.equipment, id: \.self) { equipment in ...`

Comment: Thank you for your response @JoakimDanielson! When I do that, I get "No exact matches in call to subscript" for `let equipment = exercise.equipment[index]`. Any idea on how to fix that without using `.indices`?

Comment: Look at my code sample again, what do you think the variable `equipment` at the end contains?

Comment: [Here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-views-in-a-loop-using-foreach) is an article about ForEach that should be helpful.